# Session variable in MySQL query not working using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
"UPDATE main SET latitude = '{$_POST['latitude']}', longitude = '{$_POST['longitude']}' WHERE idUser = '".$_SESSION['userId']."'""
```

But this does not work because the userId is always null in the query.

However if I echo `$_SESSION['userId']`, I get 32 (which is what I want).

And if I change the SQL to:

```
"UPDATE main SET latitude = '{$_POST['latitude']}', longitude = '{$_POST['longitude']}' WHERE idUser = 32"
```

**It magically works!!!**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code to use prepare statements, it still does not work..

```
global $conn;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE main SET latitude = ?, longitude = ? WHERE idUser = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssd", $_POST['latitude'], $_POST['longitude'], $_SESSION['userId']);
$stmt->execute();
```

It only works if I manually write the user Id I got from the echo of `$_SESSION['userId']`

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: I already did that.. Otherwise the echo would not work

Comment: Just checking *since we cannot see the rest of the code here*.

Comment: `"What am I doing wrong?"` - Quite a bit, actually.  For starters, this is wide open to SQL injection.  You should really look into prepared statements and query parameters.  As an added bonus, quoting problems kind of become moot when using parameters.

Comment: Why are you concatenating the session variable into the query? You're quoting the session variable as if it were a string. `"UPDATE main SET latitude = '{$_POST['latitude']}', longitude = '{$_POST['longitude']}' WHERE idUser = {$_SESSION['userId']}"`

Comment: In the first query,Quotes is not necessary around integers in where clause

Comment: have you tried echoing your query...? what does that prints?? also you need those inverted braces around id? its integer so...

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra double quote at the end of that string `.$_SESSION['userId']."'""`, so how that even compiles I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind multiple parameters using a single `bindParam()` command (you are also using the wrong function `bind_param()`). Also, the binding is also used for named placeholders. For your prepared statement with unnamed placeholders, simply run `execute()` using the variables as array, i.e.:

```
global $conn;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE main SET latitude = ?, longitude = ? WHERE idUser = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['latitude'], $_POST['longitude'], $_SESSION['userId']));
```

If you want to use `bindParam()`, then use:

```
global $conn;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE main SET latitude = :lat, longitude = :long WHERE idUser = :userId");
$stmt->bindParam(':lat', $_POST['latitude']);
$stmt->bindParam(':long', $_POST['longitude']);
$stmt->bindParam(':userId', $_SESSION['userId']);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Important note:** It seems like you are suppressing error reporting, as using the invalid function `bind_param()` should have thrown an error. You should enable error reporting in a development environment.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use quotes in the same manner as the $_POST variables? It must have to do with the way you're using quotes inside of that string. I find that less confusion if I always create query strings within single quotes:

```
'UPDATE main SET latitude = '". $_POST['latitude'] ."', 
longitude = '". $_POST['longitude'] ."' 
WHERE idUser = '". $_SESSION['userId'];
```

And, as the comments have mentioned, you should use prepared statements.

Comment: You don't need all of that concatenation. the variables will be interpolated properly.